# Understanding the output of with_stdout

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

Acordding to the documentation of maxima, with_stdout  is a function that evaluates some expressions and writes the output according to this expressions to a file f. I tried to use this function with a simple example:

```
with_stdout ("data.txt", for x:0 thru 10 do print (x, x^2, x^3))$
```

But the output look like this:

```
<mth><n>0</n><st> </st><n>0</n><st> </st><n>0</n><st> </st></mth><mth><n>1</n><st> </st><n>1</n><st> </st><n>1</n><st> </st></mth><mth><n>2</n><st> </st><n>4</n><st> </st><n>8</n><st> </st></mth><mth><n>3</n><st> </st><n>9</n><st> </st><n>27</n><st> </st></mth><mth><n>4</n><st> </st><n>16</n><st> </st><n>64</n><st> </st></mth><mth><n>5</n><st> </st><n>25</n><st> </st><n>125</n><st> </st></mth><mth><n>6</n><st> </st><n>36</n><st> </st><n>216</n><st> </st></mth><mth><n>7</n><st> </st><n>49</n><st> </st><n>343</n><st> </st></mth><mth><n>8</n><st> </st><n>64</n><st> </st><n>512</n><st> </st></mth><mth><n>9</n><st> </st><n>81</n><st> </st><n>729</n><st> </st></mth><mth><n>10</n><st> </st><n>100</n><st> </st><n>1000</n><st> </st></mth>
```

instead of writting a table with three columns as it is supposed to do.

I don't even understand the first output. What I am missunderstanding or missing here?

--

It seems there is a bug triggered by Wxmaxima, I don't know if it is on maxima aswell.

Regards.

Comment: On plain maxima you get the expected results, this does indeed look like a bug in wxmaxima

Answer (score 1):

Apparently wxMaxima overrides the default `print` function to generate XML tags (stuff like `<foo>` ... `</foo>`) which wxMaxima uses to indicate how stuff is displayed. I don't know if it's possible to directly call the default `print` function in wxMaxima; maybe, maybe not.

I can see a few options. (1) Call `grind` instead, which outputs the so-called 1-dimensional output. That's probably more suitable for file output anyway.

(2) Call `printf`, e.g. `printf(true, "~a, ~a, ~a~%", x, x^2, x^3)`. `printf` recognizes many output options, as described by `? printf`. It's possible `printf` calls are also intercepted by wxMaxima, I haven't tried it.

(3) Use the plain text, console Maxima interface, then `print` is sure to be the default.